# Evaluate this and also the indefinite case

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$
\mbox{How to evaluate this integral ?:}\quad
\int_{-1}^{1}\left[\,x^{2012}\sin\left(\,x\,\right) +
\frac{1}{x^{2} + 1}\,\right]\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: First part is odd, second is the derivative of $\arctan(x)$

Comment: The 1st part is odd function, so the value is zero, and the 2nd part is a simple integration.

Comment: If you want to receive answers, you must show what you try about it. That's what MSE-people is waiting for. In addition, check the [$\LaTeX$-$\texttt{MathJax}$ Tutorial of this Site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Welcome to MSE !!!. Enjoy it !!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Use $\displaystyle I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$$\displaystyle I+I=\int_a^b\{f(x)+f(a+b-x)\}\ dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Your $x^{2012}\sin x$ is odd function. so integrating it form $-x$ to $x$ will result to $0$. This leaves you with

$$\int_{-1} ^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}x|^{1}_{-1}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering the general case of $$I_n=\int x^n \sin(x)\,dx$$ integrate by parts $(u=x^n,v'=\sin(x)\,dx)$ to get $$I_n=-x^n \cos(x)+n \int x^{n-1} \cos (x)\,dx=-x^n \cos(x)+n J_{n-1}$$ Repeat the process $(u=x^{n-1},v'=\cos(x)\,dx)$ to get $$J_{n-1}=x^{n-1} \sin (x)-(n-1)\int x^{n-2} \sin (x)\,dx=x^{n-1} \sin (x)-(n-1)I_{n-2}$$ Recombine to get a simple recurrence relation betwenn $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}$ and $I_0$ seems to be quite easy.