# Evaluating a definite integral involving $ \tan^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The question is to evaluate $$\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \frac{e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x}}{e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x}+e^{\tan^{-1} \cos x}}dx$$

I tried to take idea from the graph of $\tan^{-1} \tan x$ and rewrite the integral as $$\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \frac{e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x}}{e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x}+e^{\tan^{-1} -\cos x}}dx$$.I couldn't proceed from here.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: You might want to use the half angle substitution. Express $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Comment: It might help to know that $\tan ^{-1}(\sin (x)) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and that $\tan ^{-1}(\cos (x)) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

Comment: Use the idea from here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276051/evaluate-this-and-also-the-indefinite-case/2276052#2276052

Comment: from where does it come?

Comment: Also required https://www.quora.com/Is-the-arctan-x-the-same-thing-as-arctan-x

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it came from Indian Statistical Institute B.Stat Admission Test 2007

Comment: do you have a Link to the problem?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I tried that but it seems to me that it is not working in this case.

Comment: @Pink, Can you please share where you are stuck by following the two links I've shared.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee after adding the two definite integral in question we get $$2I=\int_{\pi/2}^{\5\pi/2} e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x} \frac{2e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x}}{(e^{\tan^{-1} \cos x }+e^{\tan ^{-1}\sin x})(e^{-\tan^{-1} \cos x} + e^{\tan^{-1} \sin x})}$$

Comment: I couldn't clear the denominator.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I couldn't find the link.This link contains sample papers http://www.isical.ac.in/~deanweb/bstatsamp09.html

Comment: @Pink, $$\dfrac{1/b}{\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b}=\dfrac a{a+b}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon enforcing the substitution $x=\pi/2 -y$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{e^{\arctan(\sin(x))}}{e^{\arctan(\sin(x))}+e^{\arctan(\cos(x))}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{\arctan(\cos(y))}}{e^{\arctan(\cos(y))}+e^{\arctan(\sin(y))}}\,dy\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Noting that the integrand is $2\pi$-periodic, we can write

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{\arctan(\cos(y))}}{e^{\arctan(\cos(y))}+e^{\arctan(\sin(y))}}\,dy=\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{e^{\arctan(\cos(y))}}{e^{\arctan(\cos(y))}+e^{\arctan(\sin(y))}}\,dy \tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we see that

$$I=\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{e^{\arctan(\cos(x))}}{e^{\arctan(\sin(x))}+e^{\arctan(\cos(x))}}\,dx  \tag 3$$

Therefore, by adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ and dividing by $2$ yields the coveted result

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{e^{\arctan(\sin(x))}}{e^{\arctan(\sin(x))}+e^{\arctan(\cos(x))}}\,dx=\pi$$