# Integral of positive continuous function

Tags: integration

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a strictly positive continuous function. How can I show that 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)} dx = \frac{1}{2},$$ 
any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276051/evaluate-this-and-also-the-indefinite-case/2276052#2276052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)} dx+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)} dx=1.$$

Comment: I have a feeling that the denominator should be with a $+$ sign, rather than a $-$. Formally, the calculation is correct, but the denominator $f(x) - f(1-x)$ changes sign on $[0,1]$, so the function is not (Riemann) intégrable.

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the good hint!

Answer (score 2):

Put $y=1-x$, add the transformed integral to the original, note that the integrand becomes $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I see it!